# django admin - sometimes inlines is missing

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
     suggestion = models.ForeignKey("VideoSuggestion", null=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s %s' % (self.title, self.description)

class VideoSuggestion(models.Model):
     sugestion_literal = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.sugestion_literal

class VideoVariation(models.Model):
      video = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='variations')

      def __unicode__(self):
          return u"Variations"
```

admin.py

```
class VideoVariationInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = VideoVariation

class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [
          VideoVariationInline,
      ]
```

**sometimes**, only sometimes, I am getting error

```
ValidationError([u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'])
```

when I want to save a new object and save the existing one

what I noticed is, the Inline Form (`VideoVariationInline`) is missing in these cases.

I have read that this can be caused by `__unicode__` method, but I have them all correct, right? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your Django version, browser, and server? HTTP errors may cause loss of ManagementForm data... See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18568 as an example.

Comment: @Selcuk django1.5, chrome, nginx.